# CS50x - Filter (blur) - Receiving a runtime error on first nested else state + seeking for feedback on length of code

Tags: c, cs50

[Terminal photo HERE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtgqZ.png)I'm currently having a runtime error and have tried modifying my code but it will not pass. 
If there is any specific pointers I could get (no pun intended) to help me approach this issue.

I'm also seeking some feedback on the length of my code - I wrote it as it came to my head and I'm aware that I could make this more short and coherent.

I'm currently working on filtering each independent pixel within the image grid.

Would one suggest writing code as it comes to our head or spend more time trying to decipher an algorithm much simpler.

The code would be the following: 
any feedback is welcomed!

```
// Blur image
void
blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            int redAvg, greenAvg, blueAvg;

            if (i == 0) {

                if (j == 0) {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed / 4.0;
                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen / 4.0;
                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue / 4.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }
                if (j == width - 1) {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed / 4.0;
                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen / 4.0;
                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue / 4.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }
                else {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed / 6.0;

                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - +1].rgbtGreen / 6.0;

                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue / 6.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }
            }

            if (i > 0 && i < i - 2) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed / 6.0;

                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen / 6.0;

                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue / 6.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }

                if (j == width - 1) {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed / 6.0;

                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen / 6.0;

                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue / 6.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }
            }

            else if (i == i - 1) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed / 4.0;
                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen / 4.0;
                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue / 4.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }
                if (j == width - 1) {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed / 4.0;
                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen / 4.0;
                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue / 4.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }
                else {
                    redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed / 6.0;

                    greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen / 6.0;

                    blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue / 6.0;

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
                }
            }
            else {
                redAvg = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed / 9.0;

                greenAvg = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen / 9.0;

                blueAvg = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue / 9.0;

                image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo in `else if (i == i - 1)`? I must say, the code would be a lot easier if you simply have two more nested loops from `i-1` to `i+1` and from `j-1` to `j+1` skipping the loops which are off the image. You could cut away all the repetition, and opportunity for typos.

Comment: Assuming `RGBTRIPLE ` is a struct of u8 values?

Comment: Yes, I was able to correct that typo -- thanks!. 
As far as the two more nested loops you suggest, I'm not following. sorry @WeatherVane

Comment: yes @MichaelDorgan

Comment: Seems that you are averaging as you go, but this means you are pulling from already averaged pixels and double averaging?  You may want output to be its own buffer to prevent that.

Comment: Dividing by a float doesn't really do anything.  If you want to round instead of truncate, consider either calling round, or pass in a +` 0.5f`, where the FP value could be useful.

Comment: What I mean is `for(int p=i-1; p<=i+1; p++) { for (int q=j-1; q<=j+1; q++) { if (p>=0 && p<height && q>=0 && q<width) ...` and so on. One very simple nested loop which sums up to 9 pixels (keep count).

Comment: And to follow up on @WeatherVane, you can do range checking within his loop can `continue` on out of bounds values.  Then you just need to track how many items are being averaged, should be possible with a simple counter.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, thank you both. I will go ahead and implement these ideas to shorten the code!

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you need a separate output matrix to prevent average of averages.

Using relative offset values and some limit checks, you can simplify the function.

Also, you may need to do "saturation math" (e.g. prevent a 256 value from wrapping to 1 because it gets stored into a byte). This may not be necessary if `avg / count` is always <= 255, but I've included the code to show this

Here's a refactored version:

```
// Blur image
void
blur(int height, int width,
    RGBTRIPLE image[height][width],
    RGBTRIPLE imgout[height][width])
{
    //RGBTRIPLE *src;
    RGBTRIPLE *dst;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        dst = &imgout[i][0];

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++, dst++) {
            int redAvg = 0, greenAvg = 0, blueAvg = 0;
            int curcnt = 0;

            for (int yoff = -1;  yoff <= 1;  ++yoff) {
                int ycur = i + yoff;

                // row index out of range
                if (ycur < 0)
                    continue;
                if (ycur >= height)
                    continue;

                RGBTRIPLE *yptr = &image[ycur][0];

                for (int xoff = -1;  xoff <= 1;  ++xoff) {
                    int xcur = j + xoff;

                    // index into row (i.e. column index) out of range
                    if (xcur < 0)
                        continue;
                    if (xcur >= width)
                        continue;

                    RGBTRIPLE *xptr = &yptr[xcur];

                    redAvg += xptr->rgbtRed;
                    greenAvg += xptr->rgbtGreen;
                    blueAvg += xptr->rgbtBlue;

                    ++curcnt;
                }
            }

            redAvg /= curcnt;
            blueAvg /= curcnt;
            greenAvg /= curcnt;

            // prevent (e.g.) 256 from wrapping to 1 -- clip to max of byte
            // NOTE: _may_ not be necessary
            if (redAvg > 255)
                redAvg = 255;
            if (greenAvg > 255)
                greenAvg = 255;
            if (blueAvg > 255)
                blueAvg = 255;

            dst->rgbtRed = redAvg;
            dst->rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
            dst->rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
        }
    }
}
```

Note this could be made faster if the border pixels were handled outside the main loop

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a version that *might* be slightly faster:

```
// Blur image
void
blur(int height, int width,
    RGBTRIPLE image[height][width],
    RGBTRIPLE imgout[height][width])
{
    int ylim = height - 1;
    int xlim = width - 1;
    //RGBTRIPLE *src;
    RGBTRIPLE *dst;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        dst = &imgout[i][0];

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++, dst++) {
            int redAvg = 0, greenAvg = 0, blueAvg = 0;
            int curcnt = 0;

            int ylo = i - 1;
            if (ylo < 0)
                ylo = 0;

            int yhi = i + 1;
            if (yhi > ylim)
                yhi = ylim;

            for (int ycur = ylo;  ycur <= yhi;  ++ycur) {
                RGBTRIPLE *yptr = &image[ycur][0];

                int xlo = j - 1;
                if (xlo < 0)
                    xlo = 0;

                int xhi = j + 1;
                if (xhi > xlim)
                    xhi = xlim;

                for (int xcur = xlo;  xcur <= xhi;  ++xcur) {
                    RGBTRIPLE *xptr = &yptr[xcur];

                    redAvg += xptr->rgbtRed;
                    greenAvg += xptr->rgbtGreen;
                    blueAvg += xptr->rgbtBlue;

                    ++curcnt;
                }
            }

            redAvg /= curcnt;
            blueAvg /= curcnt;
            greenAvg /= curcnt;

            // prevent (e.g.) 256 from wrapping to 1 -- clip to max of byte
            // NOTE: _may_ not be necessary
            if (redAvg > 255)
                redAvg = 255;
            if (greenAvg > 255)
                greenAvg = 255;
            if (blueAvg > 255)
                blueAvg = 255;

            dst->rgbtRed = redAvg;
            dst->rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
            dst->rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Here's a version that moves more of the limit checks out of the inner loops:

```
// Blur image
void
blur(int height, int width,
    RGBTRIPLE image[height][width],
    RGBTRIPLE imgout[height][width])
{
    int ylim = height - 1;
    int xlim = width - 1;
    //RGBTRIPLE *src;
    RGBTRIPLE *dst;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        dst = &imgout[i][0];

        int ylo = i - 1;
        if (ylo < 0)
            ylo = 0;

        int yhi = i + 1;
        if (yhi > ylim)
            yhi = ylim;

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++, dst++) {
            int redAvg = 0, greenAvg = 0, blueAvg = 0;
            int curcnt = 0;

            int xlo = j - 1;
            if (xlo < 0)
                xlo = 0;

            int xhi = j + 1;
            if (xhi > xlim)
                xhi = xlim;

            for (int ycur = ylo;  ycur <= yhi;  ++ycur) {
                RGBTRIPLE *yptr = &image[ycur][0];

                for (int xcur = xlo;  xcur <= xhi;  ++xcur) {
                    RGBTRIPLE *xptr = &yptr[xcur];

                    redAvg += xptr->rgbtRed;
                    greenAvg += xptr->rgbtGreen;
                    blueAvg += xptr->rgbtBlue;

                    ++curcnt;
                }
            }

            redAvg /= curcnt;
            blueAvg /= curcnt;
            greenAvg /= curcnt;

            // prevent (e.g.) 256 from wrapping to 1 -- clip to max of byte
            // NOTE: _may_ not be necessary
            if (redAvg > 255)
                redAvg = 255;
            if (greenAvg > 255)
                greenAvg = 255;
            if (blueAvg > 255)
                blueAvg = 255;

            dst->rgbtRed = redAvg;
            dst->rgbtBlue = blueAvg;
            dst->rgbtGreen = greenAvg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey, I will review those three different versions. 
I'm not familiar with the  " -> " symbols though but I will work around it.

Comment: `->` is very standard. Simply ... If you have: `struct foo { int x; int y; }`, and then: `struct foo bar;`, you do: `bar.x = 5; int val = bar.y;`. But, if you have a _pointer_ to a struct (e.g. `struct foo *ptr = ...;`), you do: `ptr->x = 7; int val = ptr->y;` Also, note the "address of" operator `&`. Doing `image[i][j].red = ...; image[i][j].blue = ...;` everywhere is a _lot_ of text. And, it's slow because you're recalculating the indexing a lot.

Comment: To help with understanding, there is another syntax for `ptr->x = 5;`. It is: `ptr[0].x = 5;` They both generate the same machine code. The latter is more useful when comparing two elements of the same array [as for a sort]: `if (ptr[0].x > ptr[1].x) // swap ...`

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! @CraigEstey. 
Will put these into practice and return if any future questions arise.