# Pset4 for cs50x, the blur function

Tags: c, cs50, blur

I'm a starter on coding, I started learning with cs50, but I have a problem, I wrote the blur function, and it seems worked fine, the image actually blurred, but when I use test50(code testing tool on cs50), it says I didn't process the RGB information correctly. Please help me view the code.
Here is the code

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])//average rgb value of pixels arounds (9 if not on the edge)
{
    int a_blue = 0, a_green = 0, a_red =0;
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            int left = i - 1, right = i + 1, upper = j - 1, down = j + 1, time = 0; //
            int blue = 0, red = 0, green = 0;
            _Bool cnd = (left >= 0 && right <= width && upper >= 0 && down <= height);
            for(int t1 = i-1; t1 <= i + 1; t1++)
            {
                if(!cnd)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                for(int t2 = j - 1; t2 <= j + 1; t2++)
                {
                    if(!cnd)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //sum of all blue around
                    blue = blue + image[t2][t1].rgbtBlue;;
                    //sum of all red around
                    red = red + image[t2][t1].rgbtRed;
                    //sum of all green around
                    green = green + image[t2][t1].rgbtGreen;
                    time++;
                }
            }
            a_blue = rounding((float)blue/time);
            a_green = rounding((float)green/time);
            a_red = rounding((float)red/time);

            for(int t1 = i-1; t1 <= i + 1; t1++)
            {
                if(!cnd)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                for(int t2 = j - 1; t2 <= j + 1; t2++)
                {
                    if(!cnd)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //sum of all blue around
                    image[t2][t1].rgbtBlue = a_blue;
                    //sum of all red around
                    image[t2][t1].rgbtRed = a_red;
                    //sum of all green around
                    image[t2][t1].rgbtGreen = a_green;

                }
            }


        }
    }
    return;
}
```

And here's the result from test50

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "87 95 124\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "100 109 110\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "127 140 149\n"
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "127 140 149\n1..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "123 136 145\n1..."
```

And btw when I was viewing answers, I found that some prefer to type every line instead of using for loop, if I want to be a professonial coding engineer, could you tell me which is the better habit for coding?

Comment: Do you have access to the data used to test your program? Then use it to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program locally.

Comment: `right <= width` ==> `right < width`, and `upper` too. But it's worse than that: the `if(!cnd) continue; ` seems to be skipping all edge pixels.

Comment: ... it's the range of `t1` and `t2` you should be checking. And you haven't made a copy of the image to work from, so you'll be averaging from pixels that have already been averaged. Finally you don't need two sets of inner nested loops: you only set the central pixel value, not all 9.

Comment: For a working version that may help, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331838/5382650

Comment: @t0my0ung - I think, if you _want to be a professonial coding engineer,_ you shouldn't blindly follow habits, but rather make up your own mind and a well thought out decision on your own.