# CS50- PSet4 Filter-more

Tags: c, cs50

I cant find what is wrong with my code for blur function. The error states my code is unable to filter 3x3 image and 4x4 image correctly but it is able to filter middle, edge and corner pixel. Seeking help to understand what is wrong.

Below is my code for blur function:

`

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    

    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j]=image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
        {
            int counter;
            float sum_red;
            float sum_blue;
            float sum_green;

            sum_red=sum_blue=sum_green=counter=0;        


            for(int k=-1;k<2;k++)                             
            {
                for(int l=-1;l<2;l++)
                {
                    if((i+k)<0 || (i+k)>=height)     
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if((j+l)<0 || (j+1)>=width)  
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sum_red+=temp[i+k][j+l].rgbtRed;
                    sum_blue+=temp[i+k][j+l].rgbtBlue;
                    sum_green+=temp[i+k][j+l].rgbtGreen;
                    counter++;

                }
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed= round(sum_red/counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue= round(sum_blue/counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen= round(sum_green/counter);


        }
    }

    return;
}
```

`

Comment: Hard to spot typo: `(j+1)>=width` should be `(j+l)>=width`. I hope you can understand why I say you should *never* use the identifier `l` (ell). It is too easily confused with `1` (one). At the least you have to squint to tell the difference in some fonts.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh my...cant believe I spent so long trying to figure out what is wrong when it is just a typo! Thanks for spotting it out!! I will never use identifier l again.

Comment: I only spotted it on the third time I read it through. My eyes were expecting to read an `l` (ell) and that is what they saw.

Comment: See my cs50 blur answer: [CS50x - Filter (blur) - Receiving a runtime error on first nested else state + seeking for feedback on length of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331838/5382650)