# How to add a Blur effect in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am having a problem to create a Blur effect in a problem set for CS50.

I am able to understand the logic behind my code and i think it should work. The code compiles but the blur effect does not happen the way I want it to.

The idea is that a pixel will get the average RGB values from itself and the adjacent pixels and subsitute this value for the pixel. If its a centre pixel it will have a total of 9 pixels to get te average. If its a border pixel it will have 6 and if its in a corner it would de 4.

I would also appreciate if someone could explain to me how i can improve the style of my code as its very long compared to the other 3 effect i had to code (grayscale, sepia and reflection).

Thank you for your time!

This is the code that i used (includes comments):

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //Declaring all the variables in the following code
    int red, green, blue = 0;
    float r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9 = 0;
    float g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9 = 0;
    float b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9 = 0;

    //Copying all the pixels from image to temporary to be able to work with it and copy it back into image
    RGBTRIPLE temporary[height][width];

    // go through every row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // go through every column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temporary[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    //im going to try and solve this with the below code:

    // go through every row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        //go through every column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //this allows me to get all the pixels that are not in the border. i.e. middle pixels
            if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i <= height - 1 && j <= width -1)
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r6 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r7 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r8 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r9 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                red = (round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 + r6 + r7 + r8 + r9) / 9));

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g6 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g7 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g8 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g9 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                green = (round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6 + g7 + g8 + g9) / 9));

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b6 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b7 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b8 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b9 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                blue = (round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + b7 + b8 + b9) / 9));

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            //Now i start the if functions for the pixels in the corners
            if ((i == height - 1) && (j == 0))
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                red = (round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4) / 4));

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                green = (round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4) / 4));

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                blue = (round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) / 4));

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            if ( i == 0 && j == width - 1)
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                red = (round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4) / 4));

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                green = (round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4) / 4));

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                blue = (round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) / 4));

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1)
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                red = (round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4) / 4));

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                green = (round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4) / 4));

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j -  1].rgbtBlue;
                blue = (round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) / 4));

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                red = (round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4) / 4));

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                green = (round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4) / 4));

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                blue = (round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) / 4));

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            //Now i find out the pixels that are on the border but not in a corner
            if ((i > 0) && (i < height - 1) && (j = 0))
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r5 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                red = round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 + r6) / 6);

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g5 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                green = round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6) / 6);

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b5 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                blue = round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6) / 6);

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            if ((i == 0) && (j > 0) && (j < width - 1))
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r5 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                red = round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 + r6) / 6);

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g5 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                green = round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6) / 6);

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b5 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                blue = round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6) / 6);

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            if ((i == width - 1) && (j > 0) && (j < height - 1))
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r6 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                red = round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 + r6) / 6);

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g6 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                green = round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6) / 6);

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b6 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                blue = round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6) / 6);

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
            if ((i > 0) && (i < height - 1) && (j == width - 1))
            {
                r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;
                r2 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                r4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                r6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                red = round((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 + r6) / 6);

                g1 = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                g2 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                g4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                g6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                green = round((g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6) / 6);

                b1 = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                b2 = image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b3 = image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                b4 = image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b5 = image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                b6 = image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                blue = round((b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6) / 6);

                temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            }
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
            temporary[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            temporary[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            temporary[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            }

        }
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a kernel to filter the image?

Comment: Hello jtxkopt, in all honesty, i have not used a kernel before in any of my problem sets so I would not know how to apply one for now. What benefits does it have? also, do you see where i am wrong with my code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: This condition is off-by-one: `if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i <= height - 1 && j <= width - 1)` should be: `if (i > 0 && j > 0 && i < height - 1 && j < width - 1)`

Comment: This is and other lines are incorrect: `r1 = image[i][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j].rgbtRed;`. Please pay attention to which is the source image and which is the destination. There is no need to copy an array at the beginning *and* at the finish. You should either compute from `image` to `temporary` and copy it back at the end; or copy it at the beginning and compute from `temporary` to `image`.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again. I have now implemented the changes to the code but it still does not work. it filters through every pixel in every condition perfectly yet it seems that the results are not how they should be. Thank you once again for your input. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Part of the issue may be the sheer number of lines of code you have. You're replicating a lot of code in each `if`. And, whenever I see (e.g.) `r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9`, I want to rewrite this using arrays. This can be simplified with some loops. See my cs50 blur answer: [CS50x - Filter (blur) - Receiving a runtime error on first nested else state + seeking for feedback on length of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331838/5382650) for some tips

Answer (score -1):

In image filtering, you would have a kernel matrix whose size is typically 3 by 3, 5 by 5 or 7 by 7. It is also called filter window. You slide this window over the image, multiply the corresponding intensity values by the elements in the filter matrix, sum the multiplications up and set the result to the center pixel in the filter matrix. This is why its size is odd number.

For example, suppose that you want to apply a mean blur effect, you would have a kernel/filter matrix 3 by 3 that consists of all one.

This is how you can filter the image.

***PS***: *I assume that your image is not word-aligned*.

```
#define CLAMP(x, min, max) ((x) > (max) ? (max) : ((x) < (min) ? (min) : (x)) )
#define KERNELRADIUS 1
#define KERNELSIZE(r) ((r) * (r))

void init_mean_blur_kernel(double kernel[], int kernelSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < kernelSize; i++)
        kernel[i] = 1.0;
}

double kernel[KERNELSIZE(2 * KERNELRADIUS + 1)] = { 1.0 };

void apply_mean_blur(int width, int height, RGBTRIPLE image[width][height])
{

    init_mean_blur_kernel(kernel, KERNELSIZE(2 * KERNELRADIUS + 1));
    for(int y = KERNELRADIUS; y < height - KERNELRADIUS; y++)
    {
        for(int x = KERNELRADIUS; x < width - KERNELRADIUS; x++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE centerPixel = image[x][y];
            double sum[3] = { 0.0 };
            for(int dy = -KERNELRADIUS; dy <= KERNELRADIUS; dy++)
            {   
                for(int dx = -KERNELRADIUS; dx <= KERNELRADIUS; dx++)
                {
                    RGBTRIPLE kernelPixel = image[dx + x][y + dy];
                    sum[0] += kernelPixel.rgbtRed * kernel[ dx + KERNELRADIUS][dy + KERNELRADIUS];
                    sum[1] += kernelPixel.rgbtGreen * kernel[ dx + KERNELRADIUS][dy + KERNELRADIUS];
                    sum[2] += kernelPixel.rgbtBlue * kernel[ dx + KERNELRADIUS][dy + KERNELRADIUS];
                }
            }
            centerPixel[0] = CLAMP(sum[0], 0.0, 255.0); 
            centerPixel[1] = CLAMP(sum[1], 0.0, 255.0); 
            centerPixel[2] = CLAMP(sum[2], 0.0, 255.0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it is beyond the OP's current experience level to use a kernel matrix. That will follow in the task to do edge detection.

Comment: `double kernel[9] = { 1.0 };` There is something missing I guess.... You probable want each element to hold `1.0`, not only the first one.

Comment: Your general approach to loop over the pixels is flawed. You only handle pixels within the image and ignore the edge pixels.

Comment: @Gerhardh I know. This is to give the idea.

Comment: I am not sure if that makes it easier or harder for the OP to fix the issues.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think that he should re-implement the blur filter in this way. It is up to him.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Like Gerhardh says, my current experience level is a bit beneath the idea to use a kernel matrix, i understand the use of it and how it technically should work  but i cant really code it. Thank you anyways!