# valgrind - Invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, valgrind

So I'm trying to implement a blur filter to the image. It is the box blur filter. Basically you calculate average RGB values of 9 adjacent pixels and then assign new rgb values to an original pixel . I created a temp[][] array of pixels and tried to write fancy algorithm, where I calculate these values in k and p cycles.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];// creating temp array for blurred image

    //cycles for looping through the image
    for (int i=0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int counter = 0; // amount of valid pixels
            float red = 0;
            float blue = 0;
            float green = 0;
            for (int k=i-1; k < i + 2; k++) // 3*3 square for adjacent pixels rows
            {
                if(i < 0 || i>= height ) // avoiding seg fault
                {
                    continue;
                }else
                {
                    for (int p=j-1; p < j+2; p++) // 3*3 square for adjacent pixels cols
                    {
                        if(j < 0 || j >= width ) // avoiding seg fault
                        {
                            continue;
                        }else
                        {// counting averages for 3*3 matrix
                            red += image[k][p].rgbtRed;
                            blue += image[k][p].rgbtBlue;
                            green += image[k][p].rgbtGreen;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // calculating averages
            red = round(red/counter);
            blue = round(blue/counter);
            green = round(green/counter);
            // assigning blurred values for temp array
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed   = temp[i][j].rgbtRed  ;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue  = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue ;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

But I had segmentation fault and when i ran valgrind this what I got.

```
filter-more/ $ valgrind ./filter -b images/yard.bmp OUTFILE.bmp
==28342== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28342== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28342== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28342== Command: ./filter -b images/yard.bmp OUTFILE.bmp
==28342== 
==28342== Invalid read of size 1
==28342==    at 0x109B4A: blur (helpers.c:78)
==28342==    by 0x10953A: main (filter.c:105)
==28342==  Address 0x4b744bf is 1 bytes before a block of size 720,000 alloc'd
==28342==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28342==    by 0x109425: main (filter.c:78)
==28342== 
==28342== Invalid read of size 1
==28342==    at 0x109B7C: blur (helpers.c:79)
==28342==    by 0x10953A: main (filter.c:105)
==28342==  Address 0x4b744bd is 3 bytes before a block of size 720,000 alloc'd
==28342==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28342==    by 0x109425: main (filter.c:78)
==28342== 
==28342== Invalid read of size 1
==28342==    at 0x109BAD: blur (helpers.c:80)
==28342==    by 0x10953A: main (filter.c:105)
==28342==  Address 0x4b744be is 2 bytes before a block of size 720,000 alloc'd
==28342==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28342==    by 0x109425: main (filter.c:78)
==28342== 
==28342== 
==28342== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28342==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28342==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 729,136 bytes allocated
==28342== 
==28342== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28342== 
==28342== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==28342== ERROR SUMMARY: 720000 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is there any way i could fix this ?

Comment: What will happen to `image[k-1][p-1]` if  `p` or `k` is `0`?

Comment: My cs50 blur answer may help: [CS50x - Filter (blur) - Receiving a runtime error on first nested else state + seeking for feedback on length of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331838/5382650) In particular, the X/Y offsets from current pixel are -1, 0, +1 instead of 0, 1, 2

Comment: `// calculating averages` - sorry to tell you this mate, by you ain't calculating any averages there, since those variables are all integers. Note that it also makes your call to `round` effectively useless (redundant).

Comment: @VladislavSapozhnikov `red/counter`  is integer division like 7/5 is 1.  Is that your intent?  Consider `red = round(red/counter);` --> `red =(red + counter/2)/counter;` for a rounded integer division.

Comment: So initally i wrote "for (int k=i-1; k < i + 2; k++) " and if i were to go beyond my array i continue there " if(i < 0 || i>= height ) ". And assumed that i would simply skip these moments ,where i go beyond. is it wrong ? @Eugene Sh.

Comment: oh , that's right .i'll fix it @Reinstate Monica

Comment: first loop iteration you set k to be -1 (i-1), then use k as index