# CS50 - filter (more confortable) - edges filter makes the image all black except for pixels along the edge or corners

Tags: c, image-processing, cs50

Here is my function:

```c
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            double gxred = 0, gxgreen = 0, gxblue = 0;
            double gyred = 0, gygreen = 0, gyblue = 0;
            double red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;

            for(int a = -1; a <= 1; a++) {
                for(int b = -1; b <=1; b++) {

                    if(a+i >= 0 && a+i < height && b+j >= 0 && b+j < width) {
                        gxred += Gx[a+1][b+1] * image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                        gxgreen += Gx[a+1][b+1] * image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                        gxblue += Gx[a+1][b+1] * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

                        gyred += Gy[a+1][b+1] * image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                        gygreen += Gy[a+1][b+1] * image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                        gyblue += Gy[a+1][b+1] * image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                    }

                }
            }

            red = sqrt(((gxred*gxred) + (gyred*gyred)));
            if(red > 255)
                red = 255;
            green = sqrt(((gxgreen*gxgreen) + (gygreen*gygreen)));
            if(green > 255)
                green = 255;
            blue = sqrt(((gxblue*gxblue) + (gyblue*gyblue)));
            if(blue > 255)
                blue = 255;

            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;

        }
    }

    // image = temp
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

As the title says this code makes all pixels black except for the corners and edges, I have  tried to debug it using debug50 but since the images are too big I cant reach the middle pixels with the debugger, already watched some youtube tutorials and saw other people's code but I really can't tell what Im doing wrong.

Comment: See my cs50 blur answer: [CS50x - Filter (blur) - Receiving a runtime error on first nested else state + seeking for feedback on length of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331838/5382650) I don't recall using `sqrt` for this. Also, I think you need to keep a count of the number of pixel values added to the sum, so you can do (e.g.) `sum /= count;`

Comment: i think you're talking about the wrong filter, I'm trying to code [edges](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/more/#edges), filter that uses the sobel operator, and the ```sqrt``` is one of the steps.

Comment: If the image is too large for debugging, make it smaller. You should always debug with a small toy problem that reproduces the problem.

Comment: “The pixels along the edges and corners” of what? The image edge? Edges of objects? How is `RGBTRIPLE` defined? Make sure that `Gx[a+1][b+1] * image[i][j].rgbtRed` is signed. Maybe define your filter as a floating-point array instead, then you guarantee no weird integer conversions.

Comment: You are checking whether `a+i` and `b+j` are within array bounds, *but you never use these values for indexing*. Perhaps that could be a problem?